# How to sync code between two git repositories?

Tags: git

I have an ios APP with both ipad version and iphone version. They are only different in UI part.

Currently they are two separate projects and managed by respective git repositories. Every time the common code is changed in one project, I have to copy the code to the other project. This occasionally causes some bugs because some of the changed code is not copied.

---

For a single file, a sample change history looks like:

1. [In ipad project]change the **1st line** of file "a.txt", write in "ipad UI code"
2. [In iphone project]change the **1st line** of file "a.txt", write in "iphone UI code"
3. [In iphone project]change the **2nd line** of file "a.txt", write in "common code"

I want to sync the 2nd line "common code" between the two projects. And keep the difference in the 1st line.

The file "a.txt" in iphone project should be:

```
ipad UI code
common code
```

The file "a.txt" in iphone project should be:

```
iphone UI code
common code
```

Comment: The merge conflict you got is totally expected.  What is the problem then?

Comment: If the `common` module is really the same between the iPhone and iPad modules, you can put it into a Git submodule.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I know the conflict is expected. I just want to explain the process by showing commit history. Thanks for your answer about submodule. But it seems to sync modules/files between projects. Is there any way to sync code inside the files?

Comment: Submodules can do what you want.  Read about it.

Answer (score -1):

You can teach your repository of to solve conflict [rerere](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere)
Merge as soon as you can the conflict and then just merge other diff as the conflict was resolved the merge will be done without conflict.